# How to send an email in Outlook web add-in with the attachment size > 1MB?

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, office-js, add-in

I'm now developing an outlook web add-in to report a spam email by sending mail with attaching the suspicious email.
The command using in the add-in are mainly `EWS SOAP` command.
However, there is a limitation on `makeEwsRequestAsync` that the SOAP command cannot larger than 1MB

In order to solve the problem, I tried to call the `EWS` by external server, using the `getCallbackTokenAsync` to get the `EWS` token and pass to external server. But using `EWS` token on external server cannot support command `CreateItem` and `CreateAttachment`.

Here is the SOAP API that I used to create email with attachment to send, where {n} is placeholder replaced by code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Header>
    <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" soap:mustUnderstand="0" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendAndSaveCopy">
      <m:Items>
        <t:Message>
        <t:Subject>{0}</t:Subject>
        <t:Body BodyType="Text">{1}</t:Body
        <t:Attachments>
            <t:FileAttachment>
              <t:Name>{2}.eml</t:Name>
              <t:IsInline>false</t:IsInline>
              <t:ContentType>message/rfc822</t:ContentType>
              <t:Content>{3}</t:Content>
            </t:FileAttachment>
        </t:Attachments>
          <t:ToRecipients>{4}</t:ToRecipients>
        </t:Message>
      </m:Items>
    </m:CreateItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And the following code is ajax to send request to my external server:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://localhost:5001/api/ews",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "ewsUrl":ewsUrl,
                "ewsAuth":ewsAuthorizationHeaderValue,
                "ewsRequest":ewsCmd
            }),
            success: function(result) {
                var xmlDoc = parseEwsResponse(apiKey, result);
                if (xmlDoc != false) {
                    successListener(xmlDoc);
                }
                else
                {
                    failureListener();
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                showNotification("EWS Error (" + apiKey + ")", "Error on accessing EWS: " + textStatus);
                failureListener();
            }
        });
```

Is there any settings that I might need to do, or any workaround for this? Thanks.

**Updated:**

Since the environment using is On-Prem Exchange 2013 server. REST API may not be a solution in our case.

Comment: Please update your question with what you tried yourself and why it failed. Asking for tutorials is what you do and not smart because that way your question doesn't comply with SO rules. However, you are asking a valid question.. but now to get it meeting all requirements ;-)

Comment: Sorry that I thought the code is not informative before since my code is very simple. That's why I didn't add the code in question.

Comment: Please look into Microsoft Graph API/ Outlook Rest API v2.0, it lets you fetch emails using item Id and create & send new emails.

Comment: Updated on the environment. Since it is Exchange 2013 and it seems not possible to work on Graph / REST API